# Finish Activity() from a separate myJavaClass.java

Tags: android, android-intent

I have tried almost all the solutions from SO but no success :(.

I have a simple myJavaClass.java with a couple of functions.

One of the functions in myJavaClass : startActivity() starts MyCustomActivity

```
public startActivity(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyCustomActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

}

This launches MyCustomActivity() as expected.

Now I have another function in myJavaClass.java to close/finish MyCustomActivity but it is not able to do so!

I have tried

1. Making MyCustomActivity SingleTop in manifest and creating the activity via an intent as above
2. Passing an activity instance to "this" in onCreate() of MyCustomActivity and calling MyCustomActivity.activity.finish() from myJava.class but that doesnt work as well

Please help me. I have been stuck here for hours now. I know the solution is very simple and conceptual but I am a newbie. Just building Java/Android concepts!

**EDIT**

MyCustomActivity

```
public Activity activity;

OnCreate()
{
    ...
    this = activity;
}
```

MyJavaClass

```
public closeActivity(Context context)
{

        Activity customActivity = MyCustomActivity.activity;
        customActivity.finish();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your closing function?

Comment: How can myJavaClass.java close MyCustomActivity? Do you mean myJavaClass.java is running on a separate thread?

Comment: As I said, I might be doing something very conceptual wrong so please bear with me. I have just started java/android. This is whats happening on a high level. An SMS Broadast receiver listens for a specific message and if triggered, it calls startActivity() of MyJavaClass (which is a simple library class consisting of all the functions). This successfully launches MyCustomActivity via an intent as shown in the snippet. Now the same SMSBroadcastReceiver is suppose to call closeActivity() which in turn should finish() MyCustomActivity which is being displayed(active)

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion but i am getting a null listener. Please suggest : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994298/myactivity-implements-custom-listener-from-myclass-java-but-listener-is-always-n

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that what you are trying to do is fundamentally bad. For a start, outside of the Activity code, there are no guarantees that the activity still exists - the memory manager may have cleaned it up, the user may have pressed Back etc. Think of Activities as independent entities - you can start them, and you can optionally get a result back when they finish what they're doing, but that's it.

Think about whether you **really** have to programmatically close the activity from outside it - I'd say this is an unusual design, but there are circumstances where it may be appropriate.

If so, what I think you want is a publish/subscribe system whereby MyCustomActivity can register a listener with MyJavaClass, and then receive a callback whereupon it can 'finish' itself.

```
public Activity activity implements FinishListener
{
  public void onCreate(...)
  {
      //where does MyJavaClass come from? see in a minute
      MyJavaClass myjava = getMyJavaclass();

      myJava.addFinishListener( this );
  }

  public void onFinishCallback()
  {
      this.finish();
  }
}
```

and

```
   public class MyJavaClass
   {
      private List<FinishListener> finishListeners = ...;

      public void addFinishListener( FinishListener fl )
      {
         this.finishListeners.add(fl);
      }

      public closeActivity(Context context)
      {
         for ( FinishListener fl : finishListeners )
         {
            fl.onFinishCallback();
         }
      }
   }
```

and

```
   public interface FinishListener
   {
       void onFinishCallback();
   }
```

Now the only remaining issue is how to get MyJavaClass from the Activity. That's up to you - you may already know how, you may be able to put it in your Application implementation, it could be a singleton (bad), the listeners could be static (bad) or various other options.

Oh, and don't forget to remove the listener again in the Activity's `onDestroy()` method!

Comment: somehow I feel this is the exact thing I am looking for. Though I just got 60% of what u said coz I am a newbie. I'll google and try to understand the rest 40%. Thnx!

Answer (score 2):

Just try this....

```
public closeActivity(Activity _activity)
{
      _activity.finish();
}
```

Comment: have you tried this solution also tell how you are calling this function

Comment: but from where will closeActivity() get the parameter _activity? closeActivity() is a function in a java class and is being called from a broadCastReceiver.

Comment: got any solution are need help

Answer (score 2):

you can't finish activity from other class until you have the reference of instance of Activity in that class, give the reference in that class and call finish() method to stop the activity.

```
activity.finish();
```

Comment: I did give an instance/activity to "this" in onCreate() of MyCustomActivity and then referred it from MyJavaClass but the finish() doesnt work. No error. It just doesnt close the activity!