# MyActivity implements Custom Listener from MyClass.java but Listener is always NULL

Tags: android

MyActivity implements a CustomListener defined in MyClass.java. I have a function defined in MyClass that should trigger the listener and do some action(finish() MyActivity) defined in the activity. Somehow, I am getting null reference to the listener. Where am I going wrong?

Please refer to the code below!

**MyActivity.java**

```
import com.project.MyClass.CustomListener;

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements CustomListener {

    Context context;
    CustomListener listener;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;

        myClass = new MyClass(context);
        myClass.setOnCustomListener(listener);

    }

    public void doThisWhenTriggered()
    {
    ...
    }

}
```

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass{

    private Contect ctx;
    ArrayList<CustomListener> listeners = new ArrayList<CustomListener>();

    public MyClass(Context context)
    {
        super();
        this.ctx = context
    }

public interface CustomListener
{
       public void doThisWhenTriggered();
}


public void setOnCustomListener(CustomListenerListener listener)
{
    this.listeners.add(listener);
}

    public void generateTrigger()
    {
        CustomListener listener = listeners.get(0);

        if(listener != null)
            listener.doThisWhenTriggered();
        else
            Log.d("MyAPP", "Listener is NULL");
    }

}
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    callMyClass(Context context)
}

public void callMyClass(Context context)
{
    MyClass myClass= new myClass(context);
    myClass.generateTrigger(context);
}
```

**EDIT**

The problem was BECAUSE of accessing different instances of MyClass in BroadcastReceiver and Listeners list as correctly pointed out by @Binyamin Sharet

The solution is to declare the listener list as static and also  public void generateTrigger() as static so that the receiver's callMyClass looks like :

```
public void callMyClass(Context context)
{
    MyClass.generateTrigger(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never instantiate `listener` (declared as `CustomListener listener;`) and therefore its always null, you just need to set the activity as the listener, as it implements the interface:

```
myClass.setOnCustomListener(this);
```

As seen in your code, you create a new instance of the class in the receiver, so the listener you set does not exist in the listeners list of new instance, since the list is not static.

Comment: myClass.setOnCustomListener(ctx); => myClass.setOnCustomListener(this);

 but CustomListener listener = listeners.get(0);
 is still  NULL :(

Comment: Are you sure the same instance of MyClass is used in both places?

Comment: Im not very sure what are pointing to? the code mentioned in the question is exactly what i am using. im sure its something to do with improper instantiation but where, im nt able to figure out....btw myClass.setOnCustomListener(this) passes a reference to the activity but in MyClass(), public void setOnCustomListener(CustomListenerListener listener) is expecting a listener. is that correct?

Comment: I don't see the code that uses MyClass (who triggers the listener by calling `generateTrigger`)

Comment: An SMSBroadcasrReceiver calls MyClass.generateTrigger() . Question Edited

Comment: See my edit. regarding solution to your case, I'm not familiar enough with your app, so I'm not sure what should you do.

Comment: Yup! I guess you are right. Can you please suggest a soln? How can I get the same class instance that in the receiver to be available in listeners list? Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Its because

```
 MyClass myClass = new myClass(context);
```

in `MyBroadcastReceiver.java`. This will create a new instance.

So I think it will be better to use `MyClass.java` as Singleton.

```
public class MyClass {

    private Contect ctx;
    ArrayList<CustomListener> listeners = new ArrayList<CustomListener>();
    private static final MyClass singletonMyClass = new MyClass();

    private MyClass() {
    }

    public static CustomListner getInstance() {
        return singletonMyClass;
    }

    public interface CustomListener {
        public void doThisWhenTriggered();
    }

    public void setOnCustomListener(CustomListenerListener listener) {
        this.listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void generateTrigger() {
        CustomListener listener = listeners.get(0);

        if (listener != null)
            listener.doThisWhenTriggered();
        else
            Log.d("MyAPP", "Listener is NULL");
    }

}
```

**from `MyActivity.java` you can call**

```
MyClass myClass = MyClass.getInstance();
myClass.setOnCustomListener(listener);
```

and similarly in MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public void callMyClass(Context context)
{

    MyClass myClass= MyClass.getInstance();
    myClass.generateTrigger();

}
```

Hope this helps!!!.