# In android finishing the activity from a class

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity

I am trying to finish the activity from a class, if any exception is thrown. 
I am doing something like this:

**Class A:**

**Constructor**

```
public A(Context context){
   this.context=context;
   read();
 }

private void read(){
  try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new  ObjectInputStream(context.getAssets().open("Somefile.bin"));
   }catch (IOException e) {

    Log.d("Lets check","IOException");
    ((ActivityName)context).finish();
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
A a=new A(this);
```

From activity, calling the class A to read somefile , if any exception is thrown, it should finish the activity. As mentioned above, i do finish on the activity's context. But this is not working? Please clarify why and how this can be resolved.?

Comment: where do you use this `A a=new A(this);` in the onCreate()?

Comment: how is it not working? I tried it, and it worked fine.

Comment: See this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977881/finish-activity-from-a-separate-myjavaclass-java

Comment: it also works fine on my device(LT26i Android4.0.4)...Would you like to provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Make a public function in A class:

```
public static finishA(){
this.finish();
}
```

Then call `finishA()` from B class.

Answer (score 0):

try to finish it from same activity class using delegate....

activity

```
   public MyActivity extends Activity implements EndActivity
    {
        .
        .
        .
        @override
        public void endActivity()
        {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

EndActivity.java

> public interface EndActivity
>       {
>           public void endActivity();
>       }

A.java

```
public A
{
    private EndActivity endActivity;
    public A(EndActivity endActivity)
    {
       this.endActivity=endActivity;
       read();
     }

    private void read()
    {
      try
      {
         ObjectInputStream ois = new  ObjectInputStream(context.getAssets().open("Somefile.bin"));
       }
       catch (IOException e)
       {
           Log.d("Lets check","IOException");
           endActivity.endActivity();
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and then do the normal call from activity

```
A a=new A(this);
```

Answer (score -1):

From main activity pass "this" to the class Constructor.

And then in class

```
Activity a;
public A(Activity a){
   this.a=a;
   read();
}

private void read(){
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new     ObjectInputStream(context.getAssets().open("Somefile.bin"));
        }catch (IOException e) {

          Log.d("Lets check","IOException");
          a.finish();
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass Activity as a parameter?